# FAQ page. Show and hide content, JQuery and CSS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an issue with showing and hiding content. I am not able to hide or show full content.

My problem is this class for styling faq-link-style. When I remove it, my read more and read less buttons/links work. I think it might be the way I wrote it in JQuery. I tried many different versions but could not get it working.
Example: $('.faq-link-style .read-more')

Is there another way to improve my code? I don't want to duplicate my code. Example: I don't want to get the content twice. Once for an intro (read less, faq-intro) And the other time for the full text (read more, faq-info)

Thanks in Advance

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="faq-all">
        <div class="faq-item">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <article>

           <div class="faq-intro">
                     <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>
          <div class="faq-info">
                     <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>

            <div class="faq-link-style">
                <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                <a href="#" class="read-less">Read Less</a>
            </div>
           </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var showChar = 600;  // How many characters are shown by default

        $('.faq-intro').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {
                var s = $(this).html();
                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                var html = c + " ... ";
                $(this).html(html);
            }

            if(content.length < showChar){
                $(this).parent().find('.read-less').hide();
                $(this).parent().find('.read-more').hide();
            }
        });

        $('.faq-info').hide();
        $('.read-less').hide();

        //read more
        $('.read-more').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.faq-info').show();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find('.read-less').show();
            $(this).siblings('.faq-intro').hide();
        })

        $('.read-less').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.faq-info').hide();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find('.read-more').show();
            $(this).siblings('.faq-intro').show();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong, it should be:

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
     $(this).hide()
            .siblings('.read-less').show().end()
            .parent()
                     .siblings('.faq-intro').hide().end()
                     .siblings('.faq-info').show();
});

$('.read-less').click(function(){
     $(this).hide()
            .siblings('.read-more').show().end()
            .parent()
                     .siblings('.faq-intro').show().end()
                     .siblings('.faq-info').hide();
});
```